# How reset form and validation after submitting form (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I want to reset form and all validation messages after submitting a form. Here is plunker:http://plnkr.co/edit/992RP8gemIjgc3KxzLvQ?p=preview

My code is bellow:

Controller:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data={fullName:''};

  $scope.submit=function(){
    console.log('submit')
    $scope.myForm.$setPristine();
    $scope.myForm.$setUntouched();
    $scope.data={fullName:''};
  }
});
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<form name="myForm" novalidate>
<div>
    <label class="control-label">Name</label>
    <input
            name="full_name"
            type="text"
            ng-model="data.fullName"
            ng-required="true">

    <p ng-if="myForm.$submitted && myForm.$invalid">Validation message</p>
</div>
<button ng-click="submit()" type="submit">
    Submit
</button>
</form>
</body>
```

My problem is:
when user enters name in the input and clicks on Submit button, validation message shouldn't be shown, because model, form and validation should be resetted. How I can do it?

I tried to use  $setPristine() and $setUntouched(), but it doesn't work for me.

Is it possible to do in AngularJS? Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26015010/angularjs-form-reset-error

Answer (score 5):

I'm surrpised but `$setpristine()` doesn't update `$submitted`.

This may not be the prettiest solution but seems to work:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.data = {
    fullName: ''
  };
  $scope.submit = function() {
    console.log('submit')
     $scope.data = {
      fullName: ''
    };
    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.myForm.$setPristine();
      $scope.myForm.$setUntouched();
      $scope.myForm.$submitted = false;
    });   
  }
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/wvJr81l7POTeql6vPe1T?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: thanks...I've used it like this:    <input id="btnModalAddNotes" ng-disabled="notesFrm.$invalid" ng-click="addNotes();notesFrm.$setPristine();notesFrm.$setUntouched();notesFrm.$submitted = false;" type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit"/>

Comment: is it possible to get all the form input value using `$scope.myForm` ?