# angularjs $setPrestine not working consistently

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The following code is a login form. With this i am able to reset the form fields and error messages on first time(both success or failure works first time). Second time i am not able to rest form fields. Also the login process also fails and doesn't show failure or success. Because the data is undefined now and On console it throw error 415(Unsupported Media Type). If i remove the reset part, the login process is working properly. What i am doing wrong with reset?

In controller:

```
 App.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', 'Users', '$window', '$location', '$rootScope', 
function($scope, Users, $window, $location, $rootScope) {

        var original = $scope.users;
        $scope.users = {};
        $scope.form = {};

    $scope.reset = function() {
            $scope.users = angular.copy(original);
            $scope.form.loginForm.$setPristine(); 
        };
    } ]);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26015010/angularjs-form-reset-error

Comment: I have done the same thing that post suggests know ?

Comment: Use $scope.form.loginForm.$setValidity();  in reset and let me know

Comment: @ Santhosh It is still same, but i dont get error 415 and nothing happens

Comment: Also add $scope.form.loginForm.$setUntouched() and let me know

Comment: Same result as above, but now error shows

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161261/discussion-between-santosh-shinde-and-user3785322).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in your case your user form field does not get reset.

Replace code `$scope.users = angular.copy(original);` by `$scope.users = {};`

Otherwise initially use `var original = $scope.users || {} ;`

For more help please check the documentation to [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms).

Hope this will help you !!