# How to reset form after submission in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, forms

I have a two field form and i want to just change the tab while submission of form and the problem is since the page is not reloading the form remains as same as previously entered.

Here is my form

```
<form name="userForm" ng-submit='manageBed.addBed(bedData);'  ng-hide="manageBed.loader">
```

manageBed is the controller
tried with

`$scope.userForm.$setPristine();` and also clearing  bedData `this.bedData={};` in controller gives that required field error.

```js
this.addBed = function(bedData) {
  Admin.addBed(this.bedData).then(function(data) {
    if (data.data.success) {
      app.loader = true;
      $timeout(function() {
        app.loader = false;
        $scope.myTabIndex = 0;
        Admin.viewBed().then(function(data) {
          if (data.data.success) {
            $scope.beds = data.data.beds;
          } else {
            $scope.nobed = true;
          }
        });
        app.bedData = {};
        $location.path('/admin/managebeds');
      }, 3000);
    } else {
      app.loader = false;
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Please do check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47825651/angularjs-setprestine-not-working-consistently/47826579#47826579

Comment: Can you please add your controller code for submit and reset ?

Comment: `this.addBed = function (bedData) {
  Admin.addBed(this.bedData).then(function (data) {
   if(data.data.success){
    app.loader = true;
    $timeout(function () {
     app.loader = false;
     $scope.myTabIndex =0;
     Admin.viewBed().then(function (data) {
      if(data.data.success){
       $scope.beds=data.data.beds;

      }
      else{
       $scope.nobed=true;

      }
     });
     app.bedData ={};
     $location.path('/admin/managebeds');
    },3000);
   }
   else{
    app.loader = false;
   }

  });
  
 };`

Comment: Why are you using app 'app.bedData' and where it is defined ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the same type of example code to [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview) and check angular form controller methods to [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController).

And in your case use following code in your controller,

```
       $scope.form={}
       var self = this;
       this.addBed = function(bedData) {
          Admin.addBed(this.bedData).then(function(data) {
            if (data.data.success) {
              self.loader = true;
              $timeout(function() {
                self.loader = false;
                $scope.myTabIndex = 0;
                Admin.viewBed().then(function(data) {
                  if (data.data.success) {
                    $scope.beds = data.data.beds;
                  } else {
                    $scope.nobed = true;
                  }
                });

                self.bedData = {};

                $scope.form.userForm.$setPristine();
                $scope.form.userForm.$setUntouched()


                $location.path('/admin/managebeds');
              }, 3000);
            } else {
              self.loader = false;
            }
          });
        };
```

And in your template add following code,

```
    <form name="form.userForm" ng-submit='manageBed.addBed(bedData);'  ng-hide="manageBed.loader">
```

Please check more details about the angular form to [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms).

Hope this will help you !!!

Comment: `self.bedData = {};` will make the field reset but the problem is there will be required field error message

Comment: Use self.userForm.$setPristine(); in your controller code after reset the bedData

Comment: angular.js:14700 TypeError: Cannot read property '$setPristine' of undefined

Comment: Use $scope in placed of self

Comment: Please check answer need to pass userForm instance to submit method

Comment: Solved it by passing it, actually what i needed is $setUntouched() function thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

if you are using states then use `$state.go($state.current,{},{reload:true})` at the end of the form submit function.

Comment: Solved it using `$setUntouched();` thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

define form     `$scope.form={};`
change form name to `name = 'form.userForm'` in HTML
and after successfull submission

```
app.bedData ={};
$scope.form.userForm.$setPristine();
$scope.form.userForm.$setUntouched();
```

this solved my issue