# How to reset validation with angular on reset?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, angularjs-validation

In our angular application we have a form with validation and a reset button.  We based it off of the examples in the documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms

The trouble happens when someone tries to reset the form when a field is in an invalid state.  My expectation is that upon reset, the field should be reset to an initial value and any validation will also be reset.  However, I haven't figured out how to clear the validationl.

This can be demonstrated in the aforementioned example from the documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms  Load the demo and type in an invalid email address (`potatoes`) and then press reset.  It resets valid fields, but not invalid.   We have tried using `$setPristine()` and fiddling with `$valid` hasn't led anywhere either.  This seems like a straight forward usecase, but I have not been able to find any answers. Please someone point how the trivial solution we have overlooked!

### Update: added code from https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms

```
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <form novalidate class="simple-form">
    Name: <input type="text" ng-model="user.name" /><br />
    E-mail: <input type="email" ng-model="user.email" /><br />
    Gender: <input type="radio" ng-model="user.gender" value="male" />male
    <input type="radio" ng-model="user.gender" value="female" />female<br />
    <button ng-click="reset()">RESET</button>
    <button ng-click="update(user)">SAVE</button>
  </form>
  <pre>form = {{user | json}}</pre>
  <pre>master = {{master | json}}</pre>
</div>

<script>
  angular.module('formExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.master = {};

      $scope.update = function(user) {
        $scope.master = angular.copy(user);
      };

      $scope.reset = function() {
        $scope.user = angular.copy($scope.master);
      };

      $scope.reset();
    }]);
</script>
```

Comment: Could you insert the code that you have messed around with?

Comment: The code example in the documentation fails the same as my code.  Should I duplicate the documentation example here?

Comment: You don't need to duplicate the documentation. It would be nice to see what you have done, however, to get an idea about what's going on.

Comment: Looks like an issue to me that AngularJS ought to resolve. At some point, the model is getting unbound to the view because the model attribute is now undefined.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular clear subform data and reset validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18648427/angular-clear-subform-data-and-reset-validation)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I found the solution here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/10027#issuecomment-62857430

The solution is to have all fields of the object set with empty value on the first place, and reset with the same kind of empty object instead of using {}.

Here a plunkr which show the solution:
https://plnkr.co/edit/qKAI4OlmCbu2HNM237Z3?p=preview

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    function getEmpty() {
      return {
      name: '',
      contact: {email: ''}
    };
    }

    $scope.manufacturer = getEmpty();

    $scope.reset = function() {
      $scope.manufacturer = getEmpty()
      $scope.form.$setPristine();
      $scope.form.$setUntouched();
      $scope.form.$setValidity();
    }
  }]);
```