# Angular: Reset validation state of all controls in a form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I need to "reset" the state (validations too) of a form every time i'm going to revalidate it. I know $setPristine() function but this doesn't reset the validation state of the controls (i want to remove ng-invalid css-class).

Is there a function to do this to all the controls in a form at once?

I'm in Angular 1.3.8

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular clear subform data and reset validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18648427/angular-clear-subform-data-and-reset-validation)

Answer (score 0):

use `$setValidity` to change the validity state and notify the form

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController

Comment: i wanted something like say to the form to spread validity to all its controls.. no the contrary sorry, like $setPristine() does