# reset all errors in form

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation

I would like to add some small functionality to the AngularJS.
It's about form validation.
Let's suppose I have a form.
I filled it and send the filled object to the server.
Server made some moves with this object and decided that 'title' field is incorrect. 
Server returns the message about invalid title (let's also suppose that this validation could be made ONLY on the server to avoid client-side validation workaround).

I added new invalid error programmatically. ($scope.myForm.title.$setValidity('bad', false));
I have the .ng-invalid-bad class that marks my title field with red border.
Ok. 
I change title and send this object to the server.
But at this time my 'description' value conflicts with title, server answers 'error in description'.
So now I have to reset all validities for all fields, and add new 'bad' validity to the 'description' field. But I didn't find the functionality to reset whole form with all fields. 
I tried $setPristine and others, but fields still have 'ng-invalid-bad' class. I can remove it only when I call $setValidity('bad', true) for each field.

I made some updates for angular.js in my local copy for this functionality.

Questions:
 1. Do I miss something in docs about this functionality? 
 2. If not - can I start to prepare my PR for angular with this feature?

```
example: http://plnkr.co/edit/aev16Y3cAxTljhctUDMI
```

- Try to fill first input, leave second one empty. Click GO! You should see second field marked with red border.
- Clean up the first input, then fill the second one with some text. Click GO! You should see all inputs marked with red border.

Comment: $setPristine() should do the trick. Do you have any code to provide or a plunkr that replicates your problem?

Comment: added plunkr link to question.

Comment: Seems like setting the validity to true is the only way as $setPristine only resets the dirty, pristine and submitted state on the form and the dirty and pristine state of all of its controls.

Comment: @engstrumpan, so what do you think? Has such functionality (I called it $resetValidities() in my local copy of angularjs) the reason to be pull-requested  to the angularjs repo?

Comment: I made a service for 'cleaning up' the form: https://gist.github.com/lpsBetty/3259e966947809465cbe

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular clear subform data and reset validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18648427/angular-clear-subform-data-and-reset-validation)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to reset all fields in the form you can simply add a reset button to the form.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="formValidationApp">

<head>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-beta.2/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.0-beta.2" data-require="angular.js@1.4.0-beta.2"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="controllers.root">
  <form name="superform" novalidate>
    <input name="title" ng-model="superObject.title" />
    <br/>
    <input name="description" ng-model="superObject.description" />
    <br/>
    <input type="reset" />
    <button ng-click="go()">go!</button>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I need to reset only errors. Not content or something else.

Comment: do you want to reset those errors by clickng a button?is that the way that you need?

Comment: Yes, something like that.