# AngularJS Form reset triggers validation error messages

Tags: angularjs, validation

I'm using [Kelp404](https://github.com/kelp404/angular-validator) for validation. After I submit the form through a HTTP post, I'm trying to reset the form.

```
// values set at initialization
_this.originalForm = {};
_this.formData = angular.copy(_this.originalForm);

// below code run in .then callback of http post

$scope.addCustomerForm.$setPristine();
$scope.addCustomerForm.$setUntouched();
_this.formData = angular.copy(_this.originalForm);
```

Now, the form is pristine and untouched with all the input variables cleared. But, the inputs are having the ng-invalid class set, which displays the error messages on the UI. I tried to set the validity also for them, but didn't help.

The code `$validator.reset($scope, 'scope.formData');` is also not working

**EDIT**: The steps outlined in the linked question/answer do not solve the issue here

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angular clear subform data and reset validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18648427/angular-clear-subform-data-and-reset-validation)

Comment: I've got the `$validator.reset()` working but it shows validation errors after I nullify the model. I've fixed it by calling the `$validator.reset() ` in a `timeout` block after I nullify the model.