# Remove all validation errors from an Angular Field

Tags: angularjs, validation

I know I can call $setValidity('errorkey', true) to clear a specific validation error from a field.  However is there a way to clear all the validation errors from a single field?

I tried $setValidity(true) but that obvious didn't work.  I guess I could loop through $error for the field and then call $setValidity.  Is there an easier way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular clear subform data and reset validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18648427/angular-clear-subform-data-and-reset-validation)

Answer (score 1):

Please use following line to remove all validations error

formName is the form name ..

```
$scope.formName.$setUntouched();-- set form to untouched
$scope.formName.$setPristine();--remove all validation error
```